# Как в вариативном товаре, в вариациях выставлять значения атрибутов?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Всё срабатывает кроме

```
$variation_product->set_attribute('size', 'polutorospalnyj');
```

или

```
update_post_meta($variation['variation_id'], 'attribute_pa_size', 'polutorospalnyj');
```

что делаю не верно?

```
if(isset($size[1])){ 
                                
$new_width = $size[1]; 
                                
update_post_meta( $variation['variation_id'], '_width', $new_width);

}else{

$new_width = " "; 
                                
update_post_meta( $variation['variation_id'], '_width', 0);

}

$variation_product->set_regular_price($regular_price); 

$variation_product->set_sale_price($sale_price); 
                            
$variation_product->set_weight($new_weight); 
                            
$variation_product->set_stock_status($stock); 
                            
$variation_product->set_description($description); 
                            
$variation_product->set_status($status);

$variation_product->set_attribute('size', 'polutorospalnyj');


//update_post_meta($variation['variation_id'], 'attribute_pa_size', 'polutorospalnyj');

$variation_product->save();

$i++;
```